# Intent is not working for moving fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I'm having trouble moving intent class fragment to activity. I'm trying to send intent from one Fragment to another Activity.
Here is the code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my Manifest File

```
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"/>
```

but it's not working for me and on another side, I have done some RND but all are same for me.
How can I Solve the issue
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: remove this android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Just use _startActivity(intent);_  instead of _getActivity().startActivity(intent);_

Comment: did it work for u ?

Comment: @Quicklearner  it's working for me

Comment: i answered to your question , upvote it so others can refer it also

Comment: @QuickLearner If is this question is valid then Upvote it.

Comment: okay , also mention everything like enough details so it can be understandable to everyone

Comment: @Quicklearner please Solve the one more issue related to PIP, please Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/56231856/10800571

Comment: okay sure dear i will check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this `android:launchMode="singleTask"` 
which looks like this

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"/>
```

if your current `activity` is `mainactivity` and you are launching it again , it will not work because launchmode is set to single task in manifest

**Solution** :- remove this tag

> android:launchMode="singleTask"